# Angular async pipe doesn't trigger change detection

Tags: angular, rxjs, angular-changedetection, async-pipe

I have this class binding which should animate my image while loading, but it never trigger.

`<img [class.animated]="loader.isLoading$ | async" src="...">`

Loader :

```
public get isLoading$(): Observable<boolean> {
    return this._isLoading$.pipe(
      // If the data arrives successfully earlier than in 250ms, no indicator should be shown
      switchMap(isLoading => isLoading ? of(true).pipe(delay(250)) : of(false))
    );
  }
```

Using vanilla javascript **works** (so I guess the Loader code is fine) :

```
ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    this.loader.isLoading$.subscribe(
        isLoading => {
          const img = document.querySelector('img') as HTMLImageElement;

          if (isLoading) {
            img.classList.add('animated');
          }
          else {
            img.classList.remove('animated');
          }
        }
    );
}
```

edit : The class binding works without the `delay(250)`, why ?

Where am I doing wrong with the class binding ? Even with `ChangeDetectionStrategy.Default` it doesn't work.

Thanks for any explanation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`isLoading$()` is a getter so it's going to be called every time change detection cycle is triggered and it will return a new RxJS chain. `async` will unsubscribe from the previous one and subscribe to the new one (that will probably emit after `this._isLoading$` emits again).

So keep just one chain. Maybe make a local variable using `isLoading$()` in your component.